# Monodevelop module - equivalent to ADO.NET Entity framework

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

I am looking for a Monodevelop module which would allow me to run ADO.NET Entity framework-like syntax. I have installed MySql.Data and successfully run stuff like string connStr = "server=localhost;user=root;database=dbname;port=3306;password=mypassword;"; MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection (connStr); which allows me to run raw sql queries to the database but would like to know what to load and how to use to have things like db.Select and db.SaveChanges possible. Thank you.

Update. I use monodevelop with mono, not with /.net/.

Comment: Do you use monodevelop with mono or .net framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Spring.NET framework with Hibernate ORM - perhaps a little bit of overkill, but worth a try!

http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/orm.html

Comment: @G25 I am afraid you would have to download and compile the packages yourself, as per default there is only a windows distribution...

Comment: You can download and use "windows" .Net binaries, they should work. Unless they depend on undocumented Microsoft features (as NHibernate used to do).

Answer (score 0):

Since mono [doesn't support](http://mono-project.com/Compatibility) Entity framework you can't use it's ORM syntax to work with databases. There are however other ORM tools like [DbLinq](http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/) (preview version should be included in mono) or you can try to look at [this](http://ormeter.net/) website and find out if some of the listed tools supports mono.

Comment: I have System.Data.Linq - is it related? Does it do what I need?

Comment: @G25: Yes, that should be it, but the problem is that there is no simple visual tool in monodevelop which maps and generate objects for you (compared to Visual Studio). You have to use DbMetal which is a command line tool if I'm not mistaken.